# How to show data of Google Sheet API Get request in a LIST Control of ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api

Please help me regarding above mentioned Question, I want to use the data coming from Google Sheet API Get Request, and show it to a List Control of Asp.Net MVC Application. I have attached a Code for a reference. The method defined in the code is provided in Google Developer Platform. Whereas they are using it a console application and i am consuming the code in web application.

```
 IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
        if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name, Major");
            foreach (var row in values)
            {
                // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[4]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
        }
        Console.Read();
```

In Foreach function I want to show data in a list and generate a view.

Comment: Finally found the answer, after API GET response we can bind the values to a Model Class and Call it to the view by binding MODEL to View approach.

Comment: Already had that thing done with MVC Razor view.